# SQL Server LAN connection works in .py but not in exe

Tags: python, sql-server, exe, lan, pymssql

I created a fairly large program written in python, and when I run it locally or on the server as a .py, it does not give me any problem.

However, if I use PyInstaller to create an executable, although it still works locally, it fails when I try to make a LAN connection, as if something in Windows or on the LAN blocks my connection.

I don't understand why in .py everything works perfectly while in .exe the program cannot connect to the SQL Server on the LAN. The program will have to connect to a SQL Server that will run on windows server 2012.

The only thing I haven't tried is trying to sign the program.

It would also be interesting to post the solution somewhere in order to help other people who have the same strange problem.

NOTE: I am using the pymssql library. I also tried using other libraries like pyodbc directly, always the same problem.

Comment: probably a firewall

Comment: maybe try using pyodbc instead of pymssql , Microsoft has announced official support for pyodbc, maybe it has something to do with pymssql not being updated and supported as frequently and such?

Comment: I have already tried to use pyodbc and in any case it gives me the exact same problem, moreover I have disabled all the firewalls in the network.

Comment: Have you considered creating a [mcve] to only test a basic connection to the remote server? If the MCVE works then the problem is something specific to your "fairly large program". If the MCVE fails then you have a more fundamental problem. FWIW, PyInstaller 3.4 works fine for me with Python 3.6 and pyodbc 4.0.26.